# Datastore and dealing with big data on matlab

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns

I have a big data set of 23 GB of tick by tick stock market data without variable names as header and no delimiters. Please see the image to get an idea of my dataset.

The data has to split into columns with the variable names and length specifies as follows

- Variable 1:Mkt, Length: 2 bytes
- Variable 2:Seg, length: 4 bytes
- Variable 3:OrderNo, length:16 bytes
- Variable 4:Time, length:14 bytes
- Variable 5:BSI, length: 1 bytes
- Variable 6:Activity, length: 1 bytes
- Variable 7:Symbol, length:10 bytes
- Variable 8:Series, length:2 bytes
- Variable 9:Volume, length: 8 bytes
- Variable 10:VolOrg , length:8 bytes
- Variable 11:Ltp, length:8 bytes
- Variable 12:Tp, length: 8 bytes
- Variable 13:MOF, length:1 bytes
- Variable 14: DD, length:1bytes
- Variable 15:FEM, length:1 bytes
- Variable 16:Ind, length:1 bytes
- Variable 17:Ins, length:1 bytes

How can I split the single column into the above number of specified columns and process in *Matlab Datastore* to extract some necessary information? I am unable to find any resources so far.

This is the screenshot of Matlab datastore preview command:
[image: screenshot of Matlab datastore preview command]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output. Please, try to avoid screenshots, use code blocks instead.

Comment: You probably need to make a custom read function for your dat files, that can further be used in a File datastore (https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.filedatastore.html)

Comment: what version of matlab are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom function to read column delimited text files. There are many options to do so, some much more efficient than others.
As far as I have experimented, `sscanf` is the most efficient function for converting large amounts of text to numerical values, although it requires the values to be separated by spaces (which requires some selections and padding). The following code should work fine and as fast as achievable without re-writing some parts of the code in C.

```
function data=customRead(filename)

%% Define the file format there %%
format = {'Mkt',     [1 2],  'str';...
          'Seg',     [3 6],  'str';...
          'OrderNo', [7 22], 'int64';...  %(64 bit because int32 has 9 digits max)
          'Time',    [23 36], 'int64';...
          'BSI',     [37 37], 'int'}; %The same goes on for other fields

%% Load the file content in memory %%
fid=fopen(filename,'r');
allData=fread(fid,Inf,'*uint8');
fclose(fid);

%% Make it an array, with one line from the dat file in each row %%
bytesPerLine = 87; % 86 bytes + 1 newline (or is it 2 for \r\n ?)
nLines = length(allData)/bytesPerLine;
allData=char(reshape(allData,[bytesPerLine,nLines])'); %Each line of the input is now stored in a row

%% Loop over format fields and populate the output structure
for ii=1:size(format,2)
   thisData= allData(format{ii,2},:); %select range from char array
   switch format{ii,3}
       case 'str'
           % cast to string
           data.(format{ii,1})=string(thisData);
       case 'int'
           thisData = [thisData,repmat(' ',[nLines,1])]'; %pad with a space after each value and transpose
           thisData = thisData(:); %make it a vector
           data.(format{ii,1})=int32(sscanf(thisData,'%d')); %read with sscanf (this is fast)
       case 'int64'
           thisData = [thisData,repmat(' ',[nLines,1])]';
           thisData = thisData(:)';
           data.(format{ii,1})=sscanf(thisData,'%li'); % %li to read as int64 
       otherwise
           error('%s : unknown format %s',format{ii,1},format{ii,3});
       end
   end
end
```

The result is a structure with each field being a column vector of *string*, *int32* or *int64*

You may then define a datastore with the custom function:

```
store = fileDatastore(location,'ReadFcn',@customRead);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will try this and let you know.